# stateParams parameter is undefined

Tags: angularjs

```
  .state('app.post', {
    url: "/post/:postId",
    views: {
      'menuContent' :{
        templateUrl: 'templates/postPages/viewPost.html',
        controller: 'ViewPostController'  
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.post.comments', {
    url: "/comments",
    views: {
      'menuContent@app' :{
        templateUrl: 'templates/postPages/post-comments.html',
        controller: 'CommentController'  
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.comments.replies', {
    url: "/replies",
    views: {
      'menuContent@app' :{
        templateUrl: 'templates/postPages/replies.html',
        controller: 'ReplyController'  
      }
    }
  })
```

Inside `post-comments.html`

```
<a class="tab-item" ui-sref="app.comments.replies({commentId:comment.id})">
  <i class="icon ion-chatbox"></i>
  Reply
</a>

angular.module("mobApp.controllers")
.controller("ReplyController",function($scope, $http, $location, $ionicModal, $stateParams){
    alert("ReplyController"+$stateParams.commentId);
```

here `commentId` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a wrong `url` for the route it should be

```
.state('app.comments.replies', {
    url: "/replies/:commentId",
    views: {
        'menuContent@app' :{
        templateUrl: 'templates/postPages/replies.html',
        controller: 'ReplyController'  
     }
}
```

You need to define the `parameter` in `url` above. Then only angular create the proper `url` to it.

This is a `ui-router` [DOC](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing), Get good understand about the parameters.

Comment: i have update my question a bit it is `app.comment.replies`

Comment: oky, I updated the answer please check, I just changed the state only :)

Comment: Error `Could not resolve 'app.comments.replies' from state 'app.post.comments'`